# Circle mask in css when zooming

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to use this zooming effect on a project of mine

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/OriginalHoverEffects/index10.html

I am using an image shaped as a circle (png) . I tried to make the containing div circular using border radius

```
.view {
   width: 132px;
   height: 132px;
   margin-left: 20px;
   float: left;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   -moz-border-radius: 66px;
   -webkit-border-radius:66px;
   -khtml-border-radius:66px;
   border-radius: 66px;
   cursor: default;
}
.view .mask,.view .content {
   width: 132px;
   height: 132px;
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
.view img {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
}
.view h2 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   font-size: 17px;
   padding: 10px;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.view p {
   font-family: Georgia, serif;
   font-style: italic;
   font-size: 12px;
   position: relative;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 10px 20px 20px;
   text-align: center;
}
.view a.info {
   display: inline-block;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 7px 14px;
   background: #000;
   color: #fff;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
   box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
.view a.info: hover {
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
.view-tenth img {
   -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
   -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
   -o-transform: scaleY(1);
   -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
   transform: scaleY(1);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
.view-tenth .mask {
   background-color: rgba(255, 231, 179, 0.3);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
}
.view-tenth h2 {
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   background: transparent;
   margin: 20px 40px 0px 40px;
   -webkit-transform: scale(0);
   -moz-transform: scale(0);
   -o-transform: scale(0);
   -ms-transform: scale(0);
   transform: scale(0);
   color: #333;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
   transition: all 0.3s linear;
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
}
.view-tenth p {
   color: #333;
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transform: scale(0);
   -moz-transform: scale(0);
   -o-transform: scale(0);
   -ms-transform: scale(0);
   transform: scale(0);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
   transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.view-tenth a.info {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transform: scale(0);
   -moz-transform: scale(0);
   -o-transform: scale(0);
   -ms-transform: scale(0);
   transform: scale(0);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
   transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.view-tenth:hover img {
   -webkit-transform: scale(10);
   -moz-transform: scale(10);
   -o-transform: scale(10);
   -ms-transform: scale(10);
   transform: scale(10);
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
}
.view-tenth:hover .mask {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
}
.view-tenth:hover h2,.view-tenth:hover p,.view-tenth:hover a.info {
   -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   -moz-transform: scale(1);
   -o-transform: scale(1);
   -ms-transform: scale(1);
   transform: scale(1);
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
}
```

but when the image zoom, it shows rectangular margin. Any help on how to mask as a circle would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you give us a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing what you've tried?

Comment: Your question is thorough, I simply request that you give us slightly more code to work with, the issue is not in what you have.

Comment: Looks like it's using `transform:scale`

Comment: i added the full css code

Answer (score 0):

```
.view: hover {
-moz-transform: scaleX(2);
-o-transform: scaleX(2);
-ms-transform: scaleX(2); 
-webkit-transform: scaleX(2);
transform: scaleX(2);
}
```

Here, the image/images with the classname *view* gets scaled 2X every time user hovers over the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try use percentges (%) instead of pixels (px).

```
-moz-border-radius: 25%;
-webkit-border-radius:25%;
-khtml-border-radius:25%;
border-radius: 25%;
```